# Highlighting a track when hovering over multi track layer in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet

See this question [Displaying different tracks from one GPX XML file in different colors in Leaflet](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/387335/177416)

I can display several tracks located in one XML file over an OSM map, example [Flights map](https://www.rudyv.be/OSM/Map.html?map=PilotePrive/Itineraires/Itineraires.xml).

Now the different tracks are a little interlaced. Is it possible to highlight a track when hovering it?

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Open Street Map</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" >
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="OpenStreetMap.png">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.4/dist/leaflet.css" >
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.4/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/Leaflet.GraphicScale.min.css" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/stylesheet.css" >

</head>
<body>

    <div id="map"></div>
    <script src="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/plugins/leaflet-omnivore/v0.2.0/leaflet-omnivore.min.js"></script>
    <script src="src/Leaflet.GraphicScale.min.js"></script>
    <script>
function getUrlParameter(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, '\\[').replace(/[\]]/, '\\]');
    var regex = new RegExp('[\\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)');
    var results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return (results === null)? '' : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
};

</script>
    <script>

        var Marker = L.icon({
        iconUrl: 'Point.png',

        iconSize:     [27, 32], // size of the icon
        iconAnchor:   [13, 32], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
        popupAnchor:  [0, -30] // point from which the popup should open relative to the iconAnchor
        });
        var Lon = getUrlParameter('Lon')
        var Lat = getUrlParameter('Lat')
        var starts = new L.LayerGroup();
        // zomerwandelingen 2018
        L.marker([Lat,Lon], {icon: Marker}).bindPopup(Lat+'<br>'+Lon).addTo(starts);

// ****************** change colors sequentially  *****************

var colors = [
'#3388ff',
'#800000',
'#9a6324',
'#808000',
'#469990',
'#000075',
'#000000', 
'#e6194b',
'#f58231',
'#ffe119',
'#bfef45',
'#3cb44b',
'#42d4f4',
'#4363d8',
'#911eb4',
'#f032e6',
'#a9a9a9',
//'#fabed4',    Pink
//'#ffd8b1',    Apricot
//'#fffac8',    Beige
//'#aaffc3',    Mint
'#dcbeff',
//'#ffffff' White
];

var n = 0;
var customLayer = L.geoJson(null, {
  style: function(feature) {
    if (!feature.properties.id) {
      feature.properties.id = n++;
    }
    var iColor = feature.properties.id % colors.length;
    return { color: colors[iColor] };
  } 
});

        var zomer = new L.LayerGroup();
        var runLayer = omnivore.gpx("../"+getUrlParameter('map'), null, customLayer)
        .on('ready', function() {
        map.fitBounds(runLayer.getBounds());
    })
    .addTo(zomer);


            var osmLink = '<a href="https://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a>'
        ;
         var osmUrl = 'https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
            osmAttrib = '&copy; ' + osmLink + ' Contributors'
            ;
        var mbAttr = 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
                '<a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +
                'Imagery © <a href="https://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
            mbUrl = 'https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=TOKEN;

        var osmMap = L.tileLayer(osmUrl, {attribution: osmAttrib}),
            satellite  = L.tileLayer(mbUrl, {id: 'mapbox.satellite',   attribution: mbAttr});           
            
         var Stamen_Terrain = L.tileLayer('https://stamen-tiles-{s}.a.ssl.fastly.net/terrain/{z}/{x}/{y}.{ext}', {
            attribution: 'Map tiles by <a href="http://stamen.com">Stamen Design</a>, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0">CC BY 3.0</a> &mdash; Map data &copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>',
            subdomains: 'abcd',
            ext: 'png'
        });     
        var standard = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.opentopomap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            attribution: 'Map data: &copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>, <a href="http://viewfinderpanoramas.org">SRTM</a> | Map style: &copy; <a href="https://opentopomap.org">OpenTopoMap</a> (<a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>)',
            maxZoom: 18
        });

        var map = L.map('map', {
            layers: [osmMap, starts, zomer],
        })
        .setView([49.21, 4.2], 8);

        var baseLayers = {  
            "OpenStreetMap": osmMap,                
            "OpenTopoMap": standard,
            "3D map" : Stamen_Terrain,
            "satellite": satellite,
        };

        var overlays = {
            "Startpunten zomer": starts,
            "zomerwandelingen" : zomer
        };

        L.control.layers(baseLayers).addTo(map);

        
        var graphicScale = L.control.graphicScale({
        position:  'bottomright',   
        fill: 'hollow',
        }).addTo(map);
    
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible. But to make question stand, please include relevant existing code, otherwise it will most likely be closed as not compliant with the GIS SE site policy.

Comment: Have a look at _Adding Interaction_ section of official Leaflet example: https://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth/

Comment: Thank you, I understand how to add intercation for MouseOn, MouseOut and clik; I don't understand how I should use L.geoJson(statesData).addTo(map); for my tracks.

Comment: Just add `onEachFeature` option to your `customLayer` GeoJSON definition and there add desired interaction as in the quoted example.

Comment: This almost works : the track is highlighted when I hoover it, but is not dis-highlighted when I leave it; I understand I must declare the variable geojson before the function resetHighlight(e) {    geojson.resetStyle(e.target);} but I must have missed something; and also bindPopup does not work anymore : can you have a last look at https://www.rudyv.be/OSM/Map2.html ?

Comment: I get error "Bounds are not valid" at line 117.

Comment: I don't have the same error as you; Hoover works fine (track is highlighted), leaving gives Cannot read property 'resetStyle' of undefined on line 42; click gives Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined on line 46; probably a given input parameter not correct.

Comment: As popup and hightlight work seprately but not together I guess I've made a syntax error but I don't find where.
Don't you have an idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously if I declare `var **customLayer** = L.geoJson (...`,

then that I use `**geoJson**.resetStyle (e.target);` as in the example it does not work.

I have to use `**customLayer**.resetStyle (e.target);`