# Display a track comment when clicking a track in Leaflet multi track layer

Tags: leaflet, geojson, gpx

See this question [Displaying different tracks from one GPX XML file in different colors in Leaflet](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/387335/177416)

If I hover a track the hand transforms into an index pointer but if I click nothing happens, see example [Flights map](https://www.rudyv.be/OSM/Map.html?map=PilotePrive/Itineraires/Itineraires.xml).

How can I add a comment to ta trk or trksg tag in the XML file so that this comment is displayed when clicking on the track ?

Here is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Open Street Map</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" >
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="OpenStreetMap.png">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.4/dist/leaflet.css" >
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.4/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/Leaflet.GraphicScale.min.css" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/stylesheet.css" >

</head>
<body>

    <div id="map"></div>
    <script src="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/plugins/leaflet-omnivore/v0.2.0/leaflet-omnivore.min.js"></script>
    <script src="src/Leaflet.GraphicScale.min.js"></script>
    <script>
function getUrlParameter(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, '\\[').replace(/[\]]/, '\\]');
    var regex = new RegExp('[\\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)');
    var results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return (results === null)? '' : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
};

</script>
    <script>

        var Marker = L.icon({
        iconUrl: 'Point.png',

        iconSize:     [27, 32], // size of the icon
        iconAnchor:   [13, 32], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
        popupAnchor:  [0, -30] // point from which the popup should open relative to the iconAnchor
        });
        var Lon = getUrlParameter('Lon')
        var Lat = getUrlParameter('Lat')
        var starts = new L.LayerGroup();
        // zomerwandelingen 2018
        L.marker([Lat,Lon], {icon: Marker}).bindPopup(Lat+'<br>'+Lon).addTo(starts);

// ****************** change colors sequentially  *****************

var colors = [
'#3388ff',
'#800000',
'#9a6324',
'#808000',
'#469990',
'#000075',
'#000000', 
'#e6194b',
'#f58231',
'#ffe119',
'#bfef45',
'#3cb44b',
'#42d4f4',
'#4363d8',
'#911eb4',
'#f032e6',
'#a9a9a9',
//'#fabed4',    Pink
//'#ffd8b1',    Apricot
//'#fffac8',    Beige
//'#aaffc3',    Mint
'#dcbeff',
//'#ffffff' White
];

var n = 0;
var customLayer = L.geoJson(null, {
  style: function(feature) {
    if (!feature.properties.id) {
      feature.properties.id = n++;
    }
    var iColor = feature.properties.id % colors.length;
    return { color: colors[iColor] };
  } 
});

        var zomer = new L.LayerGroup();
        var runLayer = omnivore.gpx("../"+getUrlParameter('map'), null, customLayer)
        .on('ready', function() {
        map.fitBounds(runLayer.getBounds());
    })
    .addTo(zomer);


            var osmLink = '<a href="https://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a>'
        ;
         var osmUrl = 'https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
            osmAttrib = '&copy; ' + osmLink + ' Contributors'
            ;
        var mbAttr = 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
                '<a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +
                'Imagery © <a href="https://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
            mbUrl = 'https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=TOKEN;

        var osmMap = L.tileLayer(osmUrl, {attribution: osmAttrib}),
            satellite  = L.tileLayer(mbUrl, {id: 'mapbox.satellite',   attribution: mbAttr});           
            
         var Stamen_Terrain = L.tileLayer('https://stamen-tiles-{s}.a.ssl.fastly.net/terrain/{z}/{x}/{y}.{ext}', {
            attribution: 'Map tiles by <a href="http://stamen.com">Stamen Design</a>, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0">CC BY 3.0</a> &mdash; Map data &copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>',
            subdomains: 'abcd',
            ext: 'png'
        });     
        var standard = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.opentopomap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            attribution: 'Map data: &copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>, <a href="http://viewfinderpanoramas.org">SRTM</a> | Map style: &copy; <a href="https://opentopomap.org">OpenTopoMap</a> (<a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>)',
            maxZoom: 18
        });

        var map = L.map('map', {
            layers: [osmMap, starts, zomer],
        })
        .setView([49.21, 4.2], 8);

        var baseLayers = {  
            "OpenStreetMap": osmMap,                
            "OpenTopoMap": standard,
            "3D map" : Stamen_Terrain,
            "satellite": satellite,
        };

        var overlays = {
            "Startpunten zomer": starts,
            "zomerwandelingen" : zomer
        };

        L.control.layers(baseLayers).addTo(map);

        
        var graphicScale = L.control.graphicScale({
        position:  'bottomright',   
        fill: 'hollow',
        }).addTo(map);
    
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Coding question on GIS SE site require relevant existing code of what has been tried so far to be included in the question, otherwise question will most likely be closed as not compliant with the GIS SE site policy.

Comment: In order not to repeat the same code in my questions I thought it was better to put the link. Is it better to repeat the code ?

Comment: You can refer to another Question, but each should be standalone.

Comment: I have added my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GPX XML schema definition (see https://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1/) states that `<trk>` element can have several members that describe it. [Leaflet-omnivore](https://github.com/mapbox/leaflet-omnivore) plugin you are using to read GPX brings only two of them as feature properties to GeoJSON layer: `<name>` and `<desc>`.

You are already using the first one to name your tracks, so you can use the second one for description. This could look like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<gpx>
<trk>
  <name>200307V.xml</name>
  <desc>My track desciption</desc>
  <trkseg>
    <trkpt lat="50.503555275499821" lon="3.930021682754159"></trkpt>
    <trkpt lat="50.503901364281774" lon="3.930838163942099"></trkpt>
.
.
.
```

You can then access `<desc>` element in Leaflet through `feature.properties.desc`.

You can then use `onEachFeature` option to assign popup with the track description to your tracks:

```
var customLayer = L.geoJson(null, {
  style: function(feature) {
    if (!feature.properties.id) {
      feature.properties.id = n++;
    }
    var iColor = feature.properties.id % colors.length;
    return { color: colors[iColor] };
  },
  onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
    if (feature.properties.desc) {
      layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.desc);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but there is probably a mistake somewhere because this gives a white page.

Comment: I tried it and it works for me, so you must have mistake somewhere. Any errors in the browser debugger console?

Comment: Console says Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Map.html?map=VTT/Itineraires/LastYear.xml&Lat=50.50342933871207&Lon=3.93020213609537:82 

Line 82 is   onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {

Comment: This looks like you have error either in GPX XML or in your code. You'll have to learn debugging in browser by setting breakpoints in the code and inspecting variables. Is your nonworking code reachable online?

Comment: The non working code is at https://www.rudyv.be/OSM/Map2.html

Call like this : https://www.rudyv.be/OSM/Map2.html?map=PilotePrive/Itineraires/Itineraires.xml

Comment: Sorry, when modifying my code to adapt it to your example, I forgot to put comma after `style` option definition. Corrected now. But, anyway, you should be able to notice such mistake yourself on the basis of error message in the debugger console. You can't depend on others for correcting every stupid typing/syntax mistake.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not yet familiar enough with JS to find this kind of error, thanks to you.