# Leaflet error 'Cannot read property' on bindPopup

Tags: leaflet, popup

I try to display a popup when clicking on a multi tracks XML track.
This seems to work fine but JS console gives error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
    at e.fire (leaflet.js:5)
    at e._fireDOMEvent (leaflet.js:5)
    at e._handleDOMEvent (leaflet.js:5)
    at HTMLDivElement.r (leaflet.js:5)
```

Where is the problem? This is the concerned code:

```
    function popup(feature, layer) {
      if (feature.properties.desc) {
        layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.desc);
      }
    }
    var customLayer = L.geoJson(null, {
      style: function (feature) {
        if (!feature.properties.id) {
          feature.properties.id = n++;
        }
        var iColor = feature.properties.id % colors.length;
        return { color: colors[iColor] };
      },
      onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
        layer.on({
            mouseover: highlightFeature,
            mouseout: resetHighlight,
            click: popup(feature, layer)
        });
      }
    });
```

Comment: Compare you code with the answer to the question https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/387588/display-a-track-comment-when-clicking-a-track-in-leaflet-multi-track-layer

Comment: The code is effectively attaching `undefined` instead of a function as the event handler. So the event handler is not an instance of `Function` and therefore is lacking a [`call` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call), which the internals of Leaflet expect there to be. In effect, this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35428801/leaflet-marker-event-fires-at-wrong-time/35429902#35429902

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand.
The link you give says he should replace function onItemClick(id) { alert(id); } by function onItemClick(id) { return function(){ alert(id); } }
I've edited my question to show a little more of my code
mouseover and mouseout work fine, click gives Leaflet error

Comment: So you don't see difference in your implementation of popup and that in the answer? If not, I can't help you further.

Comment: can you try `feature.properties.desc.toString()` ?

Comment: @Timothy Dalton still works as well but gives the same error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined

Comment: @TomazicM in the answer you say I should use   onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
    if (feature.properties.desc) {
      layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.desc);
    }
  }
I donc't understand how I can implement this in my code (see in my question).

Comment: Problem you have is understanding the basics of JS programming. Since GIS SE is intended for GIS related problems, not JS coding problems, your question is more suited for StackOverflow site. I'll answer it, but please, in the future don't use GIS SE site as debugging site when learning JS programming, StackOverflow site is the place for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @IvanSanchez wrote in his comment, the reason for the error is that you are using function call instead of function object when defining `click` event handler. It should be `click: popup`, not `popup(feature, layer)`.

But even in that case it would not be correct, since `popup` handler would bind layer popup again and again at each click.

Correct way is to bind popup only once, as explained in the answer to the question [Display a track comment when clicking a track in Leaflet multi track layer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/387588/display-a-track-comment-when-clicking-a-track-in-leaflet-multi-track-layer).

So code could then look something like this:

```
onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
  if (feature.properties.desc) {
    layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.desc);
  }
  layer.on({
      mouseover: highlightFeature,
      mouseout: resetHighlight
  });
}
```

Comment: I did not understand how to combine popup and mouse hoover, your answer is clear and solves the problem, thank you.